# Run Python script on startup/reboot of AWS instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx

I'm running Flask on an AWS instance. My goal is to be able to have Flask running on its own, without me having to ssh into it and run

```
python app.py
```

Is there a way to have this command run every time the AWS instance itself reboots?

Comment: Which Operating System? Amazon Linux? Ubuntu?

Comment: @ReubenL. Amazon Linux, which I believe is centOS?

Comment: @ReubenL. Does it matter which Linux? `/etc/rc.local` would be a spot on both, right?

Comment: He could have answered Windows.

Comment: @BL You can run Flask within a WSGI service or setup behind Apache HTTPD or Nginx and those should keep your Flask app running

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm using Nginx as well, how would I attach Flask to this?

Comment: You can refer here, though for Ubuntu, it's just a matter of installation packages. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a way to start the python script on reboot.

On linux you will find ***/etc/init.d***  directory. You will need to write your own init.d script and put it inside /etc/init.d directory,which will indeed start your python script. Ahh ! wait its not goning to be magic. Dont worry, there is fixed format of init.d script. Script contains some basic tasks like start(),stop(),reload() etc. Just add the code that you want to run on start in start() block.

Some reference link : https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide//etc/init.d

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo '@reboot python /path/to/app.py') | crontab -
```